# Блокировка Коллекции

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Мне нужно сделать блокировку чтения и записи, при этом, во время чтения происходит удаление элементов из коллекции List

```
public static class Class {
 public static List<object> list = new List<object>();
 object Lock = new object();


 public static Add() {
   lock(Lock) {
     действия
   }
 }
 public static WriteAndDelete() {
   lock(Lock) {
     действия
   }
 }
}
```

Будет ли такой механизм работать как нужно?
То есть, даже при добавлении, требуется ожидание для потока, пока другой поток, который читает и удаляет сразу же, не закончит работу

Comment: Будет, только Lock тоже должен быть static

Comment: Если я добавлю функцию, которая без локера будет добавлять в коллекцию (Dictionary) данные, ничего не произойдет плохого? Но уже в функции WriteAndDelete в локере я их буду удалять по ключу

Comment: Dictionary - не потокобезопасен. Если в одном потоке вы в него будете добавлять данные, а во втором - одновременно с этим читать (например, чтобы удалить) - то второй поток с достаточно высокой вероятностью сорвется в бесконечный цикл (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/12/21/high-cpu-in-net-app-using-a-static-generic-dictionary/). Или оберните всю работу (включая чтение) в lock, или используйте потокобезопасную коллекцию - ConcurrentDictionary,